# Using git-svn to ignore a file just in the svn repo?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn, ignore

I'm new to git-svn and I'm trying to mirror an SVN repo in git. However, I'd like to add a readme.txt file for the git repo (show it shows up in places like github) but ignore that file in the SVN repo. Is that possible without making the mirror process (which is currently a simply bash script doing git-svn rebase and git push) really messy?

Comment: Does it hurt when the readme is in the svn repo too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an svn:ignore property to the parent directory that contains a pattern that would match the readme.txt file - you'll need to do this inside svn.

Comment: Which version of git is required for this to work? It does not with 1.7.1.

Comment: I see. It's not in git at all. It has to be separate SVN working dir (at least for the propedit).

Comment: Yeah - you need to do this via the svn toolset rather than from inside the git repository.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an access to SVN repostiory server, you may just install [SubGit](http://subgit.com) into your SVN repository. It is a real professsional Git-SVN mirror, every push to Git is translated to SVN revision, and vice versa. The translation is concurrent-safe, bidirectional and transparent: svn:ignores are translated to .gitignore, svn:eol-style to .gitattributes "eol" and "text" attributes, SVN tags to Git tags, branches to branches, merges to merges and so on.

If you don't have the access, you may use [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html) for working with the SVN repository. It supports ignores, EOLs, tags and merges translation too. But it is a personal SVN client, not a bridge.